# SQL String Troubles with Multiple Functions

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, jet

I am using a local Access Database connected to Visual Basic. My query is

```sql
SELECT RebateReceived, DatePart('yyyy',[RebateMailedDate]) AS MailedDate, Sum(RebateValue) as MoneyReceived
    FROM RebateInfoStorage
    where RebateReceived='Received'
    group by RebateReceived
    having DatePart('yyyy',[RebateMailedDate])
```

I am trying to get the columns that have the same year and the word(s) that have 'received' to identify the records that need to be summed (Added) together. I am not very familiar with the `Group By` and `Having` keywords or the `Sum()` and `DatePart()` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the DBMS will go into the RebateInfoStorage and grab all the rows where `RebateReceived = 'Received'`. Then, it'll group those records, where each group contains records where the expression `DatePart('yyyy', RebateMailedDate)` evaluates to the same value (i.e. they have the same year). Then for each group, it'll return a single result row with the year, and the sum of all the `RebateValue`s in that group. Operations happen in that order.

HAVING is like WHERE, but happens after the GROUP BY and is a condition placed on a group of records, whereas WHERE is a condition on a record.

```
SELECT
  YEAR(RebateMailedDate) AS MailedDate,
  SUM(RebateValue) as MoneyReceived
FROM
  RebateInfoStorage
WHERE
  RebateReceived = 'Received'
GROUP BY
  YEAR(RebateMailedDate);
```

EDIT: It would appear that YEAR(x) is a more appropriate function!

Comment: `DatePart('yyyy', RebateMailedDate)` and `YEAR(RebateMailedDate)` will both return the same integer value.  What makes `Year()` the more appropriate function?

Comment: The function now precisely says, in an even more brief fashion, exactly what you're after: the year. The code is clearer to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You should group by DatePart having RebateReceived='Received'. For more information about the syntax of Having you may refer to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Group by means your output table will be grouped according to unique elements in that column. For example, if there are multiple entry with 2014 as year, they will all be grouped together, and their RebateValue will be added up together. If you are grouping with RebateReceived, all the entry will be added and you will end up with a single sum.